# NetworkX problem with label and id when reading and writing GML

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have the following example, where I create a graph programmetically, write it to a GML file and read the file into a graph again.

I want to be able to use the graph loaded from file in place of the programmatically created one:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge(1,4)
nx.write_gml(g, "test.gml")
gg = nx.read_gml("test.gml", label="label")
print(gg.edges(data=True))
```

The contents of test.gml is a follows:

```
graph [
  node [
    id 0
    label "1"
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "4"
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 1
  ]
]
```

Nodes 1 and 4 from the python code are now represented by two nodes with ID 0 and 1 and labels "1" and "4"

After reading the file, I now have to access node 4 as follows:

```
gg['4']
```

Instead of

```
g[4]
```

for the original graph.

I could of course make sure to cast every node to string before looking up the node, but this is not practical for huge graphs.

An alternative would be to programmatically create (yet another) graph that is identical to `g` but with integer keys, but this is even more cumbersome.

What should I do?

Comment: How about relabelling the nodes with [`relabel_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
nx.read_gml(fpath, destringizer=int)
```

Ref:
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.gml.read_gml.html